# Roommate/co-tenant said she would renew but lied after I sign lease - invalid lease?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, rent, new-york, real-estate-leasing

So, my roommates and I planned to sign a lease renewal as co-tenants in NYC. While some of the roommates already signed it, the others changed their mind last minute. This unfortunately means the tenants that did sign must cover the costs of the open rooms, which we're struggling to do because we were under the impression that all the original tenants would stay and split the apartment costs.

However, the lease addressed the names of all the original tenants. So if some parties leave their signature fields empty, does that make the lease incomplete and valid/void for everyone?

Comment: Likely get a better answer over on:  https://law.stackexchange.com/